# c - compare letters in a string

Tags: c, strcmp

Ok, this must be easy but I'm having one of those days :-p

I have an char* array which for example purposes is as follows:

```
char* symbols [] = {"++-", "--+"};
```

I'm trying to loop over `symbols[0]` and `symbols[1]` and compare each of the chars to see if its a `+` or a `-`

I'm trying:

```
char* tmp = symbols[0];
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(tmp); i++)
{
    if(strcmp(tmp[i], "+") == 0)
    {
         printf("It's a plus!\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(tmp[i], "-") == 0)
    {
         printf("Its a minus!\n");
    }
}
```

However, when compiling I'm getting a warning:

```
comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

I assume I'm missing something basic - can anyone help me see the wood from the trees?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`symbols` is of type pointer to `char`. You need an array of pointers to `char`.
Change

```
char* symbols = {"++-", "--+"};
```

to

```
char* symbols[] = {"++-", "--+"};
```

and condition in `if`

```
if(strcmp(tmp[i], "+") == 0)
```

to

```
if(tmp[i] == '+')
```

Comment: excellent, thanks for this. didnt realise what i was doing with the double quotes -that was it all along!! great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`" "` and `' '` are not the same. Use single quotes to represent a character, otherwise it's an array of characters (which is an array).